# Is there a way to stream data change events from Azure SQL to Azure Event Hubs at scale?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-eventhub

We have a few SQL Azure instances which have a bunch of databases (like one for each department in an org) . We want to do stream processing on the data as and when there are updates to data in these individual databases.

From a scale perspective, we are looking at 10K events/day across all the databases, with a possible SLA of a few seconds to stream process an event.

We want to push data to Azure Event Hubs. Any existing Azure product offering can help here?

Answer (score 0):

Just some suggestions for feasible solutions.

If you are looking for a solution for Azure services, then logic app should be able to meet your needs, this is the official doc of sql server trigger in logic app:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure#add-a-sql-trigger

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#when-an-item-is-modified-(v2)

Or, if you can send web request from sql server when items changed like this:

https://www.botreetechnologies.com/blog/how-to-fire-a-web-request-from-microsoft-sql-server

Then you can send it to a endpoint like azure function, and use the event hub output binding, or just use the event hub sdk to send to event hub.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Any thoughts on "Kafka Connect" (hosted on Azure as AKS / HDInsight Cluster) which can handle all SQL data change actions, which can stream data into Event Hub endpoint?